# Magic square generator

Tags: code-golf, math, restricted-time

Create the shortest function to print a [magic square](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_square) of given size.

A magic square is a NxN matrix of distinct numbers and the sum of each row, column and diagonal is equal to a constant.

A magic square of size 4 is:

```
07 12 01 14
02 13 08 11
16 03 10 05
09 06 15 04
```

And the constant is 34.

The function should be able to handle inputs up to N = 30 and doesn't need to show leading zeroes.

Using Matlab's `magic` function or similar built-in function is not allowed.

More useful information: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MagicSquare.html

The output doesn't need to be pretty printed and may contain `[](){},`  or List/Array delimiters of your language. Although, it should use one line for each row

E.g.

```
1, 2,
3, 4,

((9,8), 
 (6,7))

[10 2]
[3 456]
```

PS: The corner case, when N = 2 is undefined behavior as there's no magic square of that size.

Also, the function should complete in less than **1 minute** to avoid brute force.

Comment: Does it have to be pretty-printed, or can the function return a list of lists or similar?

Comment: @Joey I Added that information

Comment: Bad codegolf example as it is an NP-complete problem unless you're cheating.

Comment: @Neil Reference?

Comment: @JBernardo:  NP-complete problems can be solved.  By calling it NP-complete, I only mean there is no efficient manner of going about solving for a magic square.  Though it would seem that I confused magic squares with [latin squares](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin_square), which *is* NP-complete.

Comment: @JBernardo: If you had written what I had wrote, you'd realize I was stating that I was wrong and that I confused magic squares with latin squares.  Not just that, but you'd realize that NP-complete does *not* mean that it cannot be done since I addressed that as well.

Comment: Does the program have to handle the trivial case where N=1?

Comment: @Peter Of The Corn Yes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Ruby, 344 characters

```
q=->n{r=0...n;n%2>0?(m=r.map{[]*n};x=n/2;y=i=0;r.map{r.map{m[y%=n][x%=n]=i+=1;x+=1;y-=1};x-=1;y+=2};m):n<5?[[16,3,2,13],[5,10,11,8],[9,6,7,12],[4,15,14,1]]:(d=q[n/2];r.map{|y|r.map{|x|4*d[b=y/2][a=x/2]-[0,3,2,1,3,0,2,1,3,0,1,2][(n/2%2<1?b<n/4?0:8:a==n/4&&b==n/4?4:a==n/4&&b==n/4+1?0:b<=n/4?0:b==n/4+1?4:8)+y%2*2+x%2]}})}
Q=->n{q[n].map{|s|p s}}
```

You can use it e.g. like

```
Q[3]
```

and the output will be

```
[8, 1, 6]
[3, 5, 7]
[4, 9, 2]
```

The solution is not yet fully golfed. Also huge squares are generated reasonably fast. It uses a recursive function `q` to generate the squares unless `n` is odd in which case the square is generated directly or `n==4` which is hard-coded.

Comment: @Franklin I didn't know how to directly calculate the square for N=4 with less chars. And for the other one, the condition N<5 is one char less than N==4.

Answer (score 1):

## Q, 50

Works for odd numbers

```
{(+)a rotate'(+)(a:((!)x)-1)rotate'x cut 1+(!)x*x}
```

usage

```
q){(+)a rotate'(+)(a:((!)x)-1)rotate'x cut 1+(!)x*x} 5
24 1  8  15 17
5  7  14 16 23
6  13 20 22 4 
12 19 21 3  10
18 25 2  9  11
```

Answer (score 1):

**Magic Square Generator in Python, <strike>127</strike> 106 characters**

**106 char code**

`#Works for odd numbers only`

```
n=5
print [[(i+j-1+n/2)%n*n+(i+2*j-2)%n+1for j in range(n)]for i in range(n)]
```

**127 char code**

`#Works for odd numbers only`

```
n=3
j,A=n/2,[[0]*n for i in[0]*n]
i=c=0
while c<n*n:c=A[i][j]=c+1;i,j=[i+1,[n,i][i>0]-1][c%n>0],[j,[n,j][j>0]-1][c%n>0]
print A
```

See: http://ajs-handling-problems-in-pythonblog.blogspot.in/2013/10/shortest-magic-square-generator-code-in.html

Comment: `[n,i][i]` returns `list index out of range` when _i = 2_, as it is after the very first iteration. Needs more testing?

Comment: my mistake! updated the code...**128 chars**

Comment: @primo 
n=3
j,A=n/2,[[0]*n for i in[0]*n]
i=c=0
while c<n*n:c=A[i][j]=c+1;i,j=[i+1,[n,i][i>0]-1][c%n>0],[j,[n,j][j>0]-1][c%n>0]
print A

Comment: @primo sorry for bad indentation..use the link to see a clean code

Comment: I've added the code to your post. I imagine that it was downvoted by someone who thought it was spam.